# Deinit UIImpactFeedbackGenerator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, haptic-feedback

I init a `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` with a timer with `TimeInterval=1.0`. After some seconds, I call the `deinitHapticFeedback()`, as described below and navigate to the next view controller, but the feedback doesn't stop and keeps occurring for about ten seconds after the new VC appears.

(Also, I tried calling `deinitHapticFeedback()` in `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`, but the same thing happens.)

Do you have any idea for a more optimal deinit function for a `UIFeedbackGenerator` ?

```
private var feedbackGenerator: UIImpactFeedbackGenerator? = nil

private func generateHapticFeedback() {
    feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
    feedbackGenerator?.prepare()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.feedbackGenerator?.impactOccurred()
    }
}

private func deinitHapticFeedback() {
    feedbackGenerator = nil
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` every time `generateHapticFeedback` method is called. So even if you set `feedbackGenerator` to `nil`, a new object will be created at this line `feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)`.

Instead of setting `feedbackGenerator` to `nil` you have invalidate your timer. If you are using `Timer` class to schedule timer you can call invalidate method like this `timer.invalidate()`.

```
private func deinitHapticFeedback() {
    timer.invalidate() // invalidate timer
}
```

You can also restart the timer as well when view controller appears again (if required).